# Trying to connect my raspberry pi ROS with my laptop outside my local network

Tags: ros, network, network-setup

I am trying to connect my pi's ROS with my laptop(master) and both of them are on different wifi connections
After configuring my environment variables I can see the topics but i cannot echo anything

laptop (master)

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.8:11311/
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.8
export ROS_HOSTNAME=$ROS_IP
```

PI

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<laptop public ip>:11311/
export ROS_IP=<pi private ip>
export ROS_HOSTNAME=$ROS_IP
```

And if I plug my PI with an ethernet in my laptop it works (still on different wifi)
but if i plug it anywhere else it doesn't echo

Answer (score 0):

What is the IP address of your robot? Of your laptop? Can you not connect them to the same network? Can you change the network address through the wireless access point's web interface? Why do they connect to different networks? We need more information to answer this question.